# why doesn't the save () command in django work?

Tags: python, django, web, django-rest-framework, pycharm

please help me solve the problem.

I study the Django framework at the course https: //webformyself.com/djang ... ign = django, everything went fine until I got to Part 1, Lesson 9.

When trying to save records to the database via the news1.save () variable, an error occurs:

```
>>> news1.save ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute (sql, params)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ sqlite3 \ base.py", line 413, in exec
ute
return Database.Cursor.execute (self, query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: table news_news has no column named updated_at
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ base.py", line 753, in save
self.save_base (using = using, force_insert = force_insert,
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ base.py", line 790, in save_base
updated = self._save_table (
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ base.py", line 895, in _save_table
results = self._do_insert (cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
return manager._insert (
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ manager.py", line 85, in manager_meth
od
return getattr (self.get_queryset (), name) (* args, ** kwargs)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ query.py", line 1254, in _insert
return query.get_compiler (using = using) .execute_sql (returning_fields)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ models \ sql \ compiler.py", line 1397, in execu
te_sql
cursor.execute (sql, params)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super (). execute (sql, params)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers (sql, params, many = False, executor = self._execute)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ utils.py", line 75, in _execute_wit
h_wrappers
return executor (sql, params, many, context)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute (sql, params)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback (traceback) from exc_value
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute (sql, params)
File "D: \ django-sites \ testsite \ venv \ lib \ site-packages \ django \ db \ backends \ sqlite3 \ base.py", line 413, in exec
ute
return Database.Cursor.execute (self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: table news_news has no column named updated_at
```

I have already started the whole course 3 times from the beginning, searched the entire Internet, but I could not find a solution.

Help me please!

error screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qocW.jpg

Comment: .OperationalError: table news_news has no column named updated_at, did you properly migrate database

Comment: Have you executed `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Thank you very much after running the commands
  python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate the error is gone!